# How to make a label above an entity ursina python

Tags: python, resize, panda3d, ursina

I have a zombie and i want a label above it about its hp and the name.
It's working but if i go far away i want the label to be resized to the scale of the zombie in the camera.
I know there is a screen_position variable in every entity but there's no screen_scale variable.
Please help me!
Thanks!

Comment: What have you got so far? Did you create a `Text` attached to `camera.ui`? Please show us your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.